# Database connection error when I am trying to connect mysql database in my YII application

Tags: php, yii

I have install YII framework successfully in my machine and create a new application by using terminal command of YII.

```
YiiRoot/framework/yiic webapp helloworld
```

The directory called helloworld is created on my web server. From there I have changed the database connection from SQLlite to MySql.

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=yii_amar',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => 'redhat456',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => '',
    ),
```

When I am testing the database connection in my YII terminal by using command.

```
protected/yiic shell
```

Then use this command to test database connection.

```
echo Yii::app()->db->connectionString;
```

It give me error.

```
exception 'CDbException' with message 'CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver' in /root/Desktop/htdocs/ayii/framework/db/CDbConnection.php:381
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Yes, In same server I am running other web application which are using same mysql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this

```
'connectionString' => 'mysqli:host=localhost;dbname=yii_amar'
```

with this

```
'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=yii_amar'
```

`dsn` should start with `mysql`.

"could not find driver" comes from `PDO`. Check if `pdo_mysql` extension installed via `phpinfo`.

Comment: Tried with mysql first but same result.